# Increment Realtime Database count on new user with Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

*** UPDATED: THIS WORKS. SEE ANSWER BELOW ***

I'm trying to write a Firebase Cloud Function that increments a Realtime Database `/userCount` value whenever a new user is created.

I've tried the following, but am getting "TypeError: userCountRef.transaction is not a function" in `incrementCountOnNewUser`.

Transactions **are working** for my other function `incrementCountOnOpen` when the value of `garage` is set to `true`, but the `ref` is derived from the `after` event object.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

// const userCountRef = functions.database.ref("/userCount"); // does NOT work
const userCountRef = admin.database().ref('/userCount'); // THIS WORKS!

exports.incrementCountOnNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  return userCountRef.transaction(count => count + 1);
});

exports.incrementCountOnOpen = functions.database.ref("/garage").onUpdate(({after}) => {
  const countRef = after.ref.parent.child('count');
  const newValue = after.val();

  return newValue
    ? countRef.transaction(count => count + 1)
    : null;
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue in my code with Cloud Firestore (not RD). The examples at https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples are very old. Your post was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the code above works! I had switched from the commented out code (which does NOT work). I guess it didn't wait long enough for it propagate after I published, because I see it working now!

Sorry for the confusion.